# `tinyMCE is not defined` after migrating site to server

Tags: tinymce, editor, migration

After migrating site tinyMCE (text editor) top bar have disappeared & text color have changed to black, I am getting 4 errors in concole and below is a snapshot of it.

[image]

I am using WordPress version: 4.2.2

I have already tried disabling all the plugins & re-uploaded wp-include files.
There are a lots of links out there on web regarding this issue but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague (Talha) solved it.

Some files in `wp-include` weren't uploaded properly because i was using FTP (Filezilla), I re uploaded the entire folder using cpanel and it worked!